# INSERT functionality in dxflib is not working

Tags: autocad, dxf, dxflib

I am testing out dxflib and have run into a problem. In the `BLOCKS` section, I tried to create a `BLOCK` of entities, but this fails to load in AutoCAD.  It loads fine in LibreCAD and decaffViewer.

Anyone out there using dxflib who can lend an assist? I'll post code fragments if it would help. I can't find any actual examples of folks using this on-line.

Comment: DXF is so frustrating, and dxflib documentation is way too sparse. There is little information regarding how the file is actually structured (i.e. if you use this, then you need that). I was able to get this working.

Comment: ACAD is picky with its content. If the block is not valid acording acad rules nothing will be loaded. I use libre cad often to "fix" broken dxf blocks. They usually also do not show up in acad. Why you use such a lib. Should be more fun to use acads way of create things automagically. Autocad stands for Automatic CAD ;)